# Whiyam I getting this unexpected behaviour constructing class objects?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, instance

I created a class named **result_line** and have been having problems with it's constructor. That is that it wasn't being assigned the expected values.
I have since created a similar, but more frugal, class named **rsltline** and this appears to work.

Here's the 2 classes :-

**result_line**

```
class result_line {
private:
    HWND rwnd;
    int result_flags;
    int result_extraflags;
public:
    result_line(HWND, int, int);
    ~result_line();
    HWND result_lineGetHWND();
    void result_lineSetHWND(HWND);
    int result_lineGetFlags();
    int result_lineGetExtraFlags();
    DINT result_lineGetBothFlags();
    void result_lineSetFlags(int);
    void result_lineSetExtraFlags(int);
    void result_lineSetBothFlags(int,int);
    void result_lineSetBothFlags(DINT);
};
// Constructor for result_line(HWND) and result_line(HWND, result_flag)
result_line::result_line(HWND rwnd, int result_flags, int result_extraflags) {
    rwnd = rwnd;
    result_flags = 30;
    result_extraflags = 40;
}
result_line::~result_line() {}
HWND result_line::result_lineGetHWND() { return rwnd; }
int result_line::result_lineGetFlags() { return result_flags; }
int result_line::result_lineGetExtraFlags() { return result_extraflags; }
DINT result_line::result_lineGetBothFlags() { return DINT(result_flags,result_extraflags); }
void result_line::result_lineSetHWND(HWND rwnd) { rwnd = rwnd; }
void result_line::result_lineSetFlags(int result_flags) { result_flags = result_flags; }
void result_line::result_lineSetExtraFlags(int result_extraflags) { result_extraflags = result_extraflags; }
void result_line::result_lineSetBothFlags(int result_flags, int result_extraflags) {
    result_flags = result_flags;
    result_extraflags = result_extraflags;
}
void result_line::result_lineSetBothFlags(DINT dint) {
    result_flags = dint.aint;
    result_extraflags = dint.bint;
}
```

**rsltline**

```
class rsltline {
private:
    HWND rlHWND;
    int rlflag1;
    int rlflag2;
public:
    rsltline(HWND, int, int);
    HWND rsltlineGetHWND();
    int rsltlineGetFlag1();
    int rsltlineGetFlag2();
};
rsltline::rsltline(HWND hwnd, int rf1, int rf2) {
    rlHWND = hwnd;
    rlflag1 = rf1;
    rlflag2 = rf2;
}
HWND rsltline::rsltlineGetHWND() { return rlHWND; }
int rsltline::rsltlineGetFlag1() { return rlflag1; }
int rsltline::rsltlineGetFlag2() { return rlflag2; }
```

I have the following code to create and then display instances using the two classes (the last using the **rsltline** class as opposed to the **result_line** class, as used by the first two) :-

```
result_line foo = result_line(0,3,6);
std::cout << "HWND=" << foo.result_lineGetHWND() <<
    "\tFLAGS=" << foo.result_lineGetFlags() <<
    "\tEXTRAFLAGS=" << foo.result_lineGetExtraFlags() <<
    std::endl;
result_line testrslt = result_line((HWND) 0,100,200);
std::cout << "HWND=" << testrslt.result_lineGetHWND() <<
    "\tFLAGS=" << testrslt.result_lineGetFlags() <<
    "\tEXTRAFLAGS=" << testrslt.result_lineGetExtraFlags() <<
    std::endl;
rsltline myrsltline = rsltline((HWND)2,4,6);
std::cout << "HWND=" << myrsltline.rsltlineGetHWND() <<
    "\tFLAGS=" << myrsltline.rsltlineGetFlag1() <<
    "\tEXTRAFLAGS=" << myrsltline.rsltlineGetFlag2() <<
    std::endl;
```

The first two return **Unexpected Results**, the last using the **rsltline** class works as expected. The results are:-

> HWND=0  FLAGS=0 EXTRAFLAGS=0
>
> HWND=0  FLAGS=1997196755 EXTRAFLAGS=0
>
> HWND=0x2        FLAGS=4 EXTRAFLAGS=6
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 35.007 s Press any key to
>   continue.

The only thing that I can think that may be causing this is the naming of the former. Although, perhaps it's simply a case of me needing to visit an optician :).

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Constructor parameters and instance variables having the exact same name is inviting disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at the `result_line` constructor:

```
// Constructor for result_line(HWND) and result_line(HWND, result_flag)
result_line::result_line(HWND rwnd, int result_flags, int result_extraflags) {
    rwnd = rwnd;
    result_flags = 30;
    result_extraflags = 40;
}
```

You declare a set of arguments, named `rwnd`, `result_flags` and `result_extraflags`. These are the same a local variables inside the constructor function body, and therefore shadows the member variables with the same name.

What happens is that you assign values to the local variables (the arguments), and not the member variables.

There are three solutions: Either use different names for the arguments, or prefix the member variables with `this->`, or use a *constructor initializer list*:

```
result_line::result_line(HWND rwnd, int result_flags, int result_extraflags)
    : rwnd{rwnd}, result_flags{30], result_extraflags{40}
{
    // Empty body
}
```

Comment: thanks it's all fixed now. That was it (I had no intention of keeping the values, that was part of the many experiments I tried to determine the problem). In fact, bar the 1st class all the code is from experimenting trying to find out where I'd gone wrong. I should've though more closely about why I used different names in the latter.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor body of `result_line`, you have written this:

```
 rwnd = rwnd;
```

which is self-assignment of the parameter. The member remains uninitialized  (like the other two members as well). You wanted to write this:

```
this->rwnd = rwnd;
```

That is one problem I can see in your code, which can be fixed as above — however, it is best to use member-initialization-list:

```
result_line::result_line(HWND rwnd, int result_flags, int result_extraflags)
  : rwnd(rwnd),
    result_flags(result_flags),
    result_extraflags(result_extraflags)
{
}
```

Here, members are initialized in the form of `X(Y)` — `X` is a member and `Y` is a parameter; `X` and `Y` could be the *same* name, but they would continue to represent what they are — *member* and *parameter*.

Comment: I personally think rwnd = rwnd is a self-assignment of the instance variable :-) But I wouldn't care who is right or wrong here because you want to assign the parameter to the instance variable, and it most definitely doesn't do that.

Comment: @gnasher729: *"I personally think rwnd = rwnd is a self-assignment of the instance variable :-)"*.... No, there is a parameter with the same name, so it is a self-assignment of the parameter. Also, the same name parameter hides the member.

Comment: @Nawaz, thanks for this. Your answer would certainly have given me a resolution. Basically I think I got mixed up with languages and their nuances.